# Resolving SpecFlow ScenarioContext being disposed errors

Tags: c#, specflow

In our application test suite we have random tests that fail with this error:
    Test 'Some_Test_Name' exceeded execution timeout period.

When we get an error like that, the test immediately following also fails with this error:
    System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
    Standard Output Messages:
       -> warning: The previous ScenarioContext was not disposed.
       -> error: Thread was being aborted.

I've tried various things to get around this, but I haven't found a way to access the ScenarioContext to dispose it in the cases where it should have been.  I've tried accessing it from BeforeScenario, but invariably, the error occurs before that gets hit.

We're resolved some of the timeout issues, but for the random ones that still occur, I'd like to be able to reduce the failures caused by the ScenarioContext issue and remove those false positives from my test results.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning `The previous ScenarioContext was not disposed` usually happens when the test either does not complete or the `AfterScenario` method throws an exception.

I believe this warning is benign and can safely be ignored. It will go away when you prevent your tests from either timing out, or allow the test to run to completion successfully (by preventing the `AfterScenario` method from throwing.

Comment: I pretty much said that.  What I explicitly stated was that I'd like to remove the false positives that occur when this happens.  When you get a test run littered with false positives, this isn't benign.

Comment: I'm sorry if you don't feel that this answered your question. I'm just explaining how this warning comes about from the specflow code. The only way to prevent the warning is to prevent the timeouts or stop the exceptions in the after scenario methods which is preventing the code which runs the cleanup from running. The other alternative is to fix the specflow code so that the scenario is cleaned up in either of the situations which cause this issue.

Comment: If you raise an issue over at the specflow github page I'll try and have a look at what can be done to fix it, but can't promise any timescales.

Comment: You cannot dispose the scenario context. This issue is in the specflow infrastructure.

Comment: @SamHolder you can actually.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I got it resolved by implementing try-finally in [AfterScenario] block.

```
try
{
    //your stuff
}
finally
{
    driver.Dispose();
}
```

In my view, this should work for you as well.

Comment: This doesn't work when running multiple tests at once, because if one fails, e.g. hits the finally, then the driver is disposed

Comment: finally should actually dispose the driver after each tests, no matter if it failed or not. That's the point of finally.

Comment: @Danny since this block of code is written in under tag '@After scenario, irrespective  of the scenario o/p finally will get executed and driver will be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void DisposeSpecFlowContext()
    {
        try
        {
            var disposableContext = ScenarioContext.Current as IDisposable;
            disposableContext.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Call this method in a `[AfterScenario()]` method. 
The trick to be able to dispose is casting it as IDisposable. Apparently this was implemented explicitly. 
If you want to be extra safe you could check for `disposableContext` to be not `null`.

[See here for explicit interface implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Comment: I think this can help in some situation, but generally won't this just move the problem? If an `AfterScenario` method throws before this one is called then this one won't be executed I don't think. If you do this in one before the last then you won't be able to use it, which might be a problem.

really this needs to be fixed in the infrastructure code. It's been a while since I looked in there so maybe it has already...